# EJS кэширование в express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

EJS шаблонизатор в Node.js включается стандартным способом:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

При этом при каждом запросе файл шаблона берется с диска, а мне бы хотелось, чтобы брался из кэша. У EJS есть стандартный способ как это сделать:

```
let ejs = require('ejs'),
LRU = require('lru-cache');
ejs.cache = new LRU(100); // LRU cache with 100-item limit
```

Только вот не понятно, как это сделать в Express. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В express есть встроенные средства кеширования скомпилированных шаблонов, так что вам не нужно кешировать шаблоны другим способом.

Смотрите, что пишут в документации, в разделе [Application Settings](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.settings.table)

| Property | Type | Description | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| view cache | Boolean | Включает кэширование скомпилированных шаблонов | true если `NODE_ENV` равно "production", в остальных случаях `undefined` |

То есть *если приложение запущено в production* то кеширование шаблонов включено по умолчанию.

Если вы хотите включить кеширование принудительно, например, в окружении отличающемся от production, то нужно добавить в приложение

```
app.set('view cache', true);
```

Comment: большое спасибо! То что нужно